# How to use remote includes in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, remote-debugging

I'm using Luna 4.4.1 and I want to include header files from a remote location. The project files are placed locally and I build them on the remote machine (with modified Eclipse's makefile). 
I've tried every suggestion I could find. RSE connections (SSH only and through RSE and RDT servers), RT connection, different paths (//conection-name/path or /path/), I've also tried making a remote project through RSE and RDT (can't make synchronized project since it requires git and I don't have root access to the remote machine).

The result is almost always the same - some path appears in Includes, but it's inactive (it's grey and I cannot browse it's content). Almost always, because somehow I managed to make it active two times (once through RSE and once through RT connection). I don't know how exactly and after restarting Eclipse it got inactive again and even when it was active I wasn't able to configure the linker to include the header files.
I've also tried linking the folder in Source Location and including such created alias. The result is always the same - the remote folder correctly appears in my project and is active, there's the folder name in Includes, but the linker doesn't recognize the header files (even if I change include statements to that folder directly, treating the alias as a local folder in my project).

Whilst using remote project I also tried to configure the remote linker (both RSE and RDT provide one), but also to no avail.

Comment: Were you able to do anything with this? I am trying to achieve the same using the 'synchronized' eclipse project. However for non project includes they are grayed out, even though eclipse can see them indexer just ignores them. Probably becuase the 'synchronize' does not fetch these includes onto local machine.